# datastax driver vs spring-data-cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

Hey I am new to Cassandra and I am friendly with Spring jdbc-template.

Can anyone please explain difference between both of them? Also can you suggest which one is good to use ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

spring-data-cassandra uses datastax's java-driver, so the decision to be made is really whether or not you need the functionality of spring-data.

Some features from spring data that may be useful for you (documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.3.0.M1/reference/html/#cassandra.core)):

1. spring xml configuration for configuring your Cluster instance (especially useful if you are already using spring).
2. object mapping component.

The java-driver also has a mapping component as well that is worth exploring.

In my opinion if you are already using spring, it is worth looking into spring-data-cassandra.  Otherwise, it would be good to start off with just the datastax java-driver.

Comment: Good answer!  I have seen lots of questions here about Spring with Cassandra, so this is good info to get out there.

Comment: Hey Andy thanks for answer, Its really helpful.

I already implement the Spring-data-Cassandra but having one small error. Can you you please take look at it? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805105/spring-data-cassandra-causes-xsd-validation-error-using-xml-configuration)