# Spring-Data-Cassandra causes XSD validation error using XML configuration

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

Heyy hello, I have some kind of error that won't affect on my project's compilation,deployment and running But it shows red mark at my configuration file for Spring-data-Cassandra also shows problem in problems menu. 
**Can any one please tell what's the issue?**

I have seen same question related to spring-data-JPA and Spring-data-* but they are not helping so I am posting this one.

here is error message:-

1. *The errors below were detected when validating the file "spring-tool.xsd" via the file "application-config.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "spring-tool.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when spring-tool.xsd is validated in the context of application-config.xml*.
2. *The errors below were detected when validating the file "spring-beans.xsd" via the file "application-config.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "spring-beans.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when spring-beans.xsd is validated in the context of application-config.xml.*

Here is my config.xml file and pom file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:cassandra="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"`

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cql 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cql/spring-cql.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra/spring-cassandra.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

    ">

<!-- Uncomment and add your base-package here:
     <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/>  -->


 <!-- Loads the properties into the Spring Context and uses them to fill 
    in placeholders in the bean definitions -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/properties/database.properties" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Cluster -->
<cassandra:cluster contact-points="${cassandra.contactpoints}"
    port="${cassandra.port}" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Session, built from the Cluster, and attaching 
    to a keyspace -->
<cassandra:session keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}" />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Default Cassandra Mapping Context used by CassandraConverter -->
<cassandra:mapping />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Default Cassandra Converter used by CassandraTemplate -->
<cassandra:converter />

<!-- REQUIRED: The Cassandra Template is the building block of all Spring 
    Data Cassandra -->
<cassandra:template id="cassandraTemplate" />
```

`</beans>`

**POM file**

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>`

```
<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    **<!-- I also try this one -->**
    <!-- <spring-framework.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring-framework.version> -->


    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cassandra Connectivity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <!-- Spring Milestone -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

`</project>`